# F = ma -- How was did we come to understand that this compact form expressed what Newton said in words?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, classical-mechanics, newton

My understanding is, Newton in the 17th century did not use this formula but rather said, in words basically that if you apply a force it will cause a mass to accelerate in the direction of that force.

How did we move from descriptive words to using multiplication to express the same idea? Many people must have said, What does multiplication have to do with exerting a force? (Indeed, I ask that same question today in the 21st century.)

Comment: [*Principia*, Definition II](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Principles_of_Natural_Philosophy_(1846)/Definitions):"*The quantity of motion is the measure of the same, arising from the velocity and quantity of matter conjunctly... in a body double in quantity, with equal velocity, the motion is double; with twice the velocity, it is quadruple.*" Nobody familiar with how proportionality works had to ask why proportionality to velocity and "quantity of matter" meant proportionality to their product. Law II then declared force to be proportional to its "alteration" (derivative).

Comment: You are right; at Newton's time the algebraic symbolism was quite new and its application to dynamics was still to be done. See [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/who-was-the-first-scientist-who-calculated-with-physical-quantities) for Euler. And see also [this one](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/mathematics-was-recreated-on-a-foundation-of-number-concepts-rather-than-geometr).

Comment: Regarding Jakob Hermann, see Niccolò Guicciardini, [An Episode in the History of Dynamics: Jakob Hermann’s Proof of Proposition 1 Book 1 of Newton’s Principia (Hist.Math. 1996)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086096900166)

Comment: See Hermann's [Phoronomia (1716)](https://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/hermanphoronomia.htm)

Comment: See [Book I, Coroll.I to Prop.I](https://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/hermann/phoronomiach.1&2.pdf): " so that if the body were $C$, and the action of gravity, by which its individual
elements may be affected, may be called $G$, the quantity or the product $C.G$ establishes the absolute weight of the body $C$, on understanding by this letter $C$ to 
 be the mass of this body."

Comment: Ans see [Sect.II, Prop.VI. Lemma](https://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/hermann/bk1sect2ch1.pdf): "The mass of the body requiring to be moved may be called M, the speed being
acquired V, and thus the motion being generated MV, so that the time to be produced
must be T , from which acting uniformly in this time the force must be $G$ , being shown to $G = M.V:T$."

Comment: And Scholium: "so that only an infinitesimal speed dV is acquired by the
moving body, because only through an infinitesimal time can its infinitesimal speed $dV$ be considered as uniform by the action of the variable G; therefore in this case there is $G =M dV : dT$ , and thus $dT = MdV : G$. Where G indicates the weight or the variable force of gravity on a mass M. "

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you just have to Wikipedia-it:

> Newton expressed his second law by saying that the force on a body is proportional to its change of motion, or momentum. By the time he wrote the *Principia*, he had already developed calculus (which he called "the science of fluxions"), but in the *Principia* he made no explicit use of it, perhaps because he believed geometrical arguments in the tradition of Euclid to be more rigorous. Consequently, the *Principia* does not express acceleration as the second derivative of position, and so it does not give the second law as $ F=ma$. This form of the second law was written (for the special case of constant force) at least as early as 1716, by [Jakob Hermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Hermann).

Note that Newton says that $F$ is proportional to $\dot p$ (the derivative/change of momentum $p= m v$). No need to have a product of anything.

Looking at Hermann's book (*Phoronomia*), he writes directly $G=M \mathrm dV/\mathrm dt$, $G$ is the weight, $M$ the mass and $V$ the speed.

Leonhard Euler wrote independently in *Novi Commentarii
academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae* that  $F=M \mathrm d^2x/\mathrm d t^2$, in 1775.

Futher reading: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/newton-principia/

Comment: I do not post for fame and profit: I am asking because I do not understand how multiplication became a shorthand for something that I do not think is clearly expressed by the equation. Newton's wording from 350 years ago is understandable, the equation is not.

Comment: @releseabe The "multiplication" is hidden in the word "proportional" with the constant of proportionality (assuming the mass is constant) being the mass. Thus, the multiplication is implicit in Newton's wording (again, assuming the mass is constant).

Comment: @releseabe can you be more specific? multiplication between what and what? In Newton's account he says it is proportional meaning that an increase in force is also a linear increase in the change of momentum.

Comment: f = ma -- multiplication seems to mean applying acceleration -- so the physical act of impelling an object becomes mathematical multiplication, quite a conceptual leap, it seems to me.

Comment: @releseabe Multiplication between acceleration and what? Mass? again Newton did not use multiplication. Newton used momentum $p=mv$, so then your question is why is momentum $m$ times $v$?